# Return to HOME after closing document

Tags: sharepoint-online, publishing-site, site, sitepages

User opens document link and when they close the document they are sent to the Documents page. I would like them to be redirected to the home page.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Per my knowledge we do not have such feature to do so. You can always access the homepage via the link on your left navigation